# Why Canvas element draw my old function after clearReact?

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, graph

I don't know what to do. I cleared my canvas and my function isn't redrawing on the graph, so I can't locate the problem. I saw in debugger mode that something bad happened in the clearReact() function. Exactly when I drawNet() again. Does my program still remember my func and add it to the graph? How?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 30;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
let rangex = canvas.width / 40;
let rangey = canvas.height / 20
let number = -20;
truthTableRPN = {
  '(': 0,
  '+': 1,
  '-': 1,
  ')': 1,
  '*': 2,
  '/': 2,
  '%': 2,
  '^': 3
}
arrayFunction = []
stos = []

drawNet()
drawNumericalInterval()
drawAxes()
ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);

function drawAxes() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.moveTo(0, centerY);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, centerY);
  ctx.moveTo(centerX, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(centerX, canvas.height);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath()
}

function drawNumericalInterval() {
  for (i = 0; i <= canvas.width; i += rangex) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillText(number, i, centerY - 9)
    number++
    ctx.textAlign = "center"
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle"
    ctx.font = "10px Arial"
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.moveTo(i, centerY - 5);
    ctx.lineTo(i, centerY + 5);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  number = 10

  for (i = 0; i <= canvas.height; i += rangey) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillText(number, centerX - 9, i)
    number--
    ctx.textAlign = "center"
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle"
    ctx.font = "10px Arial"
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.moveTo(centerX - 5, i);
    ctx.lineTo(centerX + 5, i);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function drawNet() {
  for (i = 0; i <= canvas.width; i += rangex) {
    ctx.moveTo(i, 0);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.2)";
    ctx.lineTo(i, canvas.height);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath()
  }
  for (i = 0; i <= canvas.height; i += rangey) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, i);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.2)";
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, i);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath()
  }
}

function getValue(znak) {
  let returnvalue = truthTableRPN[znak] ?? -1
  return returnvalue
}

function createRPNUserFunction() {
  const myFunction = document.querySelector("#myFunction").value
  const check = document.querySelector(".siemka")
  myFunction.replace(/\s/g, '');
  charArray = myFunction.match(/([\w\d]+)|[-\+\*\/\^\(\)]/g)

  for (i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(stos)
    console.log(arrayFunction)

    char = charArray[i]
    if (/[a-z0-9]/.test(char)) {
      arrayFunction.push(char)
    } else if (i == 0 && char == '-') {
      stos.push(char)
      arrayFunction.push(0)
    } else if (stos[stos.length - 1] == '(' && char == '-') {
      stos.push(char)
      arrayFunction.push(0)
    } else if (char === ')') {
      while (stos[stos.length - 1] !== '(') {
        arrayFunction.push(stos[stos.length - 1])
        stos.pop()
      }
      stos.pop()
    } else if (char == '+' || char == '-' || char == '/' || char == '*' || char == '^' || char == '%') {
      while (getValue(char) <= getValue(stos[stos.length - 1])) {
        arrayFunction.push(stos[stos.length - 1])
        stos.pop()
      }
      stos.push(char)
    } else stos.push(char)
  }
  for (i = 0; i <= stos.length; i++) {
    arrayFunction.push(stos.pop())
  }
  stos = ''
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayFunction.length; i++) {
    if (arrayFunction[i] == '^') arrayFunction[i] = arrayFunction[i].replace('^', "**");
  }

  return arrayFunction

  // check.innerHTML += "pokaż stos: "+stos+'<br>'
  // check.innerHTML += "pokaż wyjście: "+arrayFunction+'<br>'
  // arrayFunction =[]
  // stos =[]
}

function changeValuesOfX(number, func) {
  let temparrayFunction = func.slice();
  for (i = 0; i < temparrayFunction.length; i++) {
    if (temparrayFunction[i] == 'x') temparrayFunction[i] = number;
  }
  return temparrayFunction
}

function countYParameterFunction(func) {
  stos = []

  for (i = 0; i < func.length; i++) {
    if (/[0-9]/.test(func[i])) {
      stos.push(func[i])
    } else {
      a = stos[stos.length - 1]
      stos.pop()
      b = stos[stos.length - 1]
      stos.pop()
      stos.push(mathCalc(Number(b), Number(a), func[i]))
    }
  }
  return stos.pop()
}

function mathCalc(firstVar, secondVar, operator) {
  switch (operator) {
    case '**':
      return result = firstVar ** secondVar
      break;
    case '%':
      return result = firstVar % secondVar
      break;
    case '*':
      return result = firstVar * secondVar
      break;
    case '/':
      return result = firstVar / secondVar
      break;
    case '+':
      return result = firstVar + secondVar
      break;
    case '-':
      return result = firstVar - secondVar
      break;
  }
}

function drawFunctionGraph(arrayFunction) {
  counter = 0
  let color = document.querySelector('#color').value;
  let rangex = canvas.width / 40;
  let rangey = canvas.height / 20
  let maxPlusX = centerX
  let maxMinusY = -centerY
  let maxMinusX = -centerX
  let maxPlusY = centerY
  for (let number = -20; number <= 20; number += 0.1) {
    array = changeValuesOfX(number, arrayFunction)
    y = (countYParameterFunction(array))
    x = number * rangex
    y *= -rangey
    console.log(x, y);

    if (counter == 0 && y >= maxMinusY && y <= maxPlusY && x > maxMinusX && x < maxPlusX) {
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.strokeStyle = color
      ctx.moveTo(tempX, tempY);
      ctx.lineTo(x, y)
      ctx.stroke()
      i++
      counter++
    } else if (counter > 0) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = color
      ctx.lineTo(x, y)
      ctx.stroke()
      ctx.moveTo(x, y);
      i++
      counter++
    } else {
      tempX = x
      tempY = y
      continue
    }

    ctx.closePath()
  }
}

function clearReact() {
  ctx.translate(-centerX, -centerY);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  number = -20;
  drawNet()
  drawNumericalInterval()
  drawAxes()
  ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
}

function createNewGraphFunction() {
  arrayFunction = createRPNUserFunction()
  drawFunctionGraph(arrayFunction)
  arrayFunction = []
  stos = []
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: `something bad happened in the clearReact() function` please add some more details on what you see in the console

Answer (score 0):

In your code nothing is calling the `clearReact` function so I added a button that calls it.

I did a couple of changes:

- remove unneeded `ctx.translate`
  *(we don't need to translate all over the place, that is just confusing)*
- added `ctx.beginPath` on the drawNet
  *(this might be the root cause of your "still remember" issue)*
- added a new function to draw a circle to make sure everything clears

You can test the code below, I do not see anything wrong there

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 30;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
let rangex = canvas.width / 40;
let rangey = canvas.height / 20
let number = -20;
truthTableRPN = {
  '(': 0,
  '+': 1,
  '-': 1,
  ')': 1,
  '*': 2,
  '/': 2,
  '%': 2,
  '^': 3
}
arrayFunction = []
stos = []

drawNet()
drawNumericalInterval()
drawAxes()

function drawAxes() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.moveTo(0, centerY);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, centerY);
  ctx.moveTo(centerX, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(centerX, canvas.height);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath()
}

function drawNumericalInterval() {
  for (i = 0; i <= canvas.width; i += rangex) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillText(number, i, centerY - 9)
    number++
    ctx.textAlign = "center"
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle"
    ctx.font = "10px Arial"
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.moveTo(i, centerY - 5);
    ctx.lineTo(i, centerY + 5);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  number = 10

  for (i = 0; i <= canvas.height; i += rangey) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillText(number, centerX - 9, i)
    number--
    ctx.textAlign = "center"
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle"
    ctx.font = "10px Arial"
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.moveTo(centerX - 5, i);
    ctx.lineTo(centerX + 5, i);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function drawNet() {
  ctx.beginPath()
  for (i = 0; i <= canvas.width; i += rangex) {
    ctx.moveTo(i, 0);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.2)";
    ctx.lineTo(i, canvas.height);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath()
  }
  for (i = 0; i <= canvas.height; i += rangey) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, i);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.2)";
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, i);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath()
  }
}

function getValue(znak) {
  let returnvalue = truthTableRPN[znak] ?? -1
  return returnvalue
}

function createRPNUserFunction() {
  const myFunction = document.querySelector("#myFunction").value
  const check = document.querySelector(".siemka")
  myFunction.replace(/\s/g, '');
  charArray = myFunction.match(/([\w\d]+)|[-\+\*\/\^\(\)]/g)

  for (i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(stos)
    console.log(arrayFunction)

    char = charArray[i]
    if (/[a-z0-9]/.test(char)) {
      arrayFunction.push(char)
    } else if (i == 0 && char == '-') {
      stos.push(char)
      arrayFunction.push(0)
    } else if (stos[stos.length - 1] == '(' && char == '-') {
      stos.push(char)
      arrayFunction.push(0)
    } else if (char === ')') {
      while (stos[stos.length - 1] !== '(') {
        arrayFunction.push(stos[stos.length - 1])
        stos.pop()
      }
      stos.pop()
    } else if (char == '+' || char == '-' || char == '/' || char == '*' || char == '^' || char == '%') {
      while (getValue(char) <= getValue(stos[stos.length - 1])) {
        arrayFunction.push(stos[stos.length - 1])
        stos.pop()
      }
      stos.push(char)
    } else stos.push(char)
  }
  for (i = 0; i <= stos.length; i++) {
    arrayFunction.push(stos.pop())
  }
  stos = ''
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayFunction.length; i++) {
    if (arrayFunction[i] == '^') arrayFunction[i] = arrayFunction[i].replace('^', "**");
  }

  return arrayFunction

  // check.innerHTML += "pokaż stos: "+stos+'<br>'
  // check.innerHTML += "pokaż wyjście: "+arrayFunction+'<br>'
  // arrayFunction =[]
  // stos =[]
}

function changeValuesOfX(number, func) {
  let temparrayFunction = func.slice();
  for (i = 0; i < temparrayFunction.length; i++) {
    if (temparrayFunction[i] == 'x') temparrayFunction[i] = number;
  }
  return temparrayFunction
}

function countYParameterFunction(func) {
  stos = []

  for (i = 0; i < func.length; i++) {
    if (/[0-9]/.test(func[i])) {
      stos.push(func[i])
    } else {
      a = stos[stos.length - 1]
      stos.pop()
      b = stos[stos.length - 1]
      stos.pop()
      stos.push(mathCalc(Number(b), Number(a), func[i]))
    }
  }
  return stos.pop()
}

function mathCalc(firstVar, secondVar, operator) {
  switch (operator) {
    case '**':
      return result = firstVar ** secondVar
      break;
    case '%':
      return result = firstVar % secondVar
      break;
    case '*':
      return result = firstVar * secondVar
      break;
    case '/':
      return result = firstVar / secondVar
      break;
    case '+':
      return result = firstVar + secondVar
      break;
    case '-':
      return result = firstVar - secondVar
      break;
  }
}

function drawFunctionGraph(arrayFunction) {
  counter = 0
  let color = document.querySelector('#color').value;
  let rangex = canvas.width / 40;
  let rangey = canvas.height / 20
  let maxPlusX = centerX
  let maxMinusY = -centerY
  let maxMinusX = -centerX
  let maxPlusY = centerY
  for (let number = -20; number <= 20; number += 0.1) {
    array = changeValuesOfX(number, arrayFunction)
    y = (countYParameterFunction(array))
    x = number * rangex
    y *= -rangey
    console.log(x, y);

    if (counter == 0 && y >= maxMinusY && y <= maxPlusY && x > maxMinusX && x < maxPlusX) {
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.strokeStyle = color
      ctx.moveTo(tempX, tempY);
      ctx.lineTo(x, y)
      ctx.stroke()
      i++
      counter++
    } else if (counter > 0) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = color
      ctx.lineTo(x, y)
      ctx.stroke()
      ctx.moveTo(x, y);
      i++
      counter++
    } else {
      tempX = x
      tempY = y
      continue
    }

    ctx.closePath()
  }
}

function clearReact() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  number = -20;
  drawNet()
  drawNumericalInterval()
  drawAxes()
}

function createNewGraphFunction() {
  arrayFunction = createRPNUserFunction()
  drawFunctionGraph(arrayFunction)
  arrayFunction = []
  stos = []
}

function drawCircle() {
  let x = (Math.random()- 0.5) * 100
  let y = (Math.random()- 0.5) * 100
  ctx.moveTo(centerX + x + 40, centerY + y);
  ctx.arc(centerX + x, centerY + y, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
  ctx.stroke()
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clearReact()">clearReact</button>
<button onclick="drawCircle()">drawCircle</button>
<br/>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I have this HTML in my code:  so I have smh what calls my func<form class="menu" onsubmit="return false">
            <label> Podaj wartość funkcji: </label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Przykładowy format: x^2+4*x+4" id="myFunction">
            <label>Wybierz kolor Funkcji:</label>
            <input type="color" id="color"><br>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button class="bttn" onclick="createNewGraphFunction()">Narysuj</button>
                <button class="bttn" onclick="clearReact()">Zmarz</button>
            </div>
        </form>

Comment: @Grzegorz you should add that in the question not in the comments

Comment: @Grzegorz Did you try my suggested correction the addition of `beginPath` ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried and still after calling the function clearReact(), Canvas clears all functions except for one. It still stays on screen, but they are grey like graph net. By the way I didn't know where to put my answer cuz i use stack first time 

Comment: Nevermind! It works, I have to reload my page. Changes didn't load. ctx.beginPath() in drawNet function was needed

Comment: @Grzegorz I'm glad it worked! ... dont' forget to mark the answer and upvote